# I am having problems with Spacy

Tags: nlp, spacy

```py
import spacy

nlp = spacy.blank('en')

sentence = "From a group of 7 men and 6 women, five persons are to be selected to form a committee so that at least 3 men are there on the committee. In how many ways can it be done?"

words = sentence.split()

doc = nlp(sentence)

tokens = []

for i, token in enumerate(doc):
    if (token.is_digit or token.like_num) and (i > 0):
        tokens.append(doc[i:i+2].text)

tokens = [i.split() for i in tokens]

values = []
attributes = []

for token in tokens:
    values.append(token[0])
    attributes.append(token[1])
    
for i, j in zip(attributes, values):
    print(i, j)
```

I ran this code, normally it is showing all the values, but when I turn it to a dictionary, it doesn't show the 7 men in the question and only shows 3 men, 6 women and five persons, I don't understand the issue.

I wanted the output to extract the numeric values and their attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering stems from the fact that the dictionary keys are based on the `attributes` list. Dictionary keys should ideally be unique to avoid ambiguity; Python doesn't enforce this and will overwrite a value with an already existing key.

For example:

```
my_dict = {}

my_dict['apple']  = 1
my_dict['banana'] = 2
my_dict['apple']  = 3  # Overwrites previous value
```

It sounds like your code is working as expected otherwise; but when you convert from the list to dictionary, the key "men" is first set to 7, and then overwritten to 3.

One idea to get around this might be to use the `zip_longest` function from the `itertools` module. Here's an example:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
#...your existing code...

for i, j in zip_longest(attributes, values, fillvalue=None):
    my_dict[i] = j

print(my_dict)
```

Output should now be: `{'men': 7, 'women': 6, 'persons': 'five', 'men': 3}`

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: I cut and pasted your code with my correction above and it outputs the dictionary as above. Can you paste your full code in an edit of the original question so I can see?